# How to provide default value functionality in Typescript observable

Tags: typescript, observable

I am trying to understand how can you provide a default value in an `observable` in `TS` when one of your element of the `stream` goes in the `catch` block:

```
getClient(id:number):Observable<User>{
        let route=UserService.baseUrl+"/user/${id}";
        var data=  this.http.get(route)
        .map(resp=>resp)
        .catch((err,o)=> {console.log(error);return {};}) as Observable<User>;
        return data;
    }
```

In the above example, I understand that you either `throw` or you can provide a `default` value if the element fails to get retrieved in the `catch` block.

Why do I get this error:

```
Argument of type '(err: any, o: Observable<Object>) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Object>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{}'
```

**P.S** I have tried all combinations to make the `.catch(lambda)` compile:

`.catch((err,o)=> return {};)`
`.catch((o)=>..)`

Comment: Can u try return Observable.throw("some error " + err);

Comment: Yes it does compile.But isn't it a bit unintuitive?I mean i wouldn't  have guessed that `throw` actually returns an empty `Observable`.

Comment: I don't think catch will return an empty observable , instead it will just throw an error. what you are looking for?

Comment: You can also try something like  catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))

Comment: I want it to behave something like this: for ech element in the observable if it fails ..print the error to the console but return an empty element. `myobservable.map(...).catch(x=> {console.log(error); return [emptyelement]})`.Bottom line is : if i am expecting 10 elements and  i get 5 of them..i want for each of the other 5 to have a message in the console,but not throw .

Comment: So you want the empty observable return in catch block, when you subscribe right?

Comment: Yes i want it not to throw..I just want to send somehting like  `c#`'s `Enumerable.Empty` if there are no elements.If some failed i just want the successful ones.

Comment: Which version of RxJS you are using ? I have posted an answer can u try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183377/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-ninjajami).

Comment: I have added a sample demo for you. Please let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a new Observable on your catchBlock like below

```
 var data =  this.http.get(route).pipe(
        map(resp=>resp), catchError(this.handleError))


 private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error)
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next({status:"Error"  });
    });
   // return Observable.throw("Authentication Failed  " + error.statusText);
  }
```

Sample Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-catch-error-return?file=index.ts

Comment: how about map block has some thing to do? it won't be mapped if created a new observable.